# Objective-C: How to format string as $ Price

Tags: objective-c, formatting, currency

Is their a built-in way of formatting string as $ price, e.g. `12345.45` converted to `$12,345.45`?

Comment: What type is holding the number?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Assuming you are using Cocoa (or just Foundation), you can use NSNumberFormatter and set its style to currency:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
... = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

By default it uses the locale of your system, but you can change that and lots of other properties, see the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API docs.

Comment: I figured it out on my own. Thanks anyways :).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the price is held in a float, you probably want [+localizedStringWithFormat:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/localizedStringWithFormat:).

```
NSString *priceString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"$ %'.2f",price];
```

Hmmm... Apple says they follow the [IEEE standard for printf](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), so it should accept the ' flag, but it doesn't work on Tiger. `NSNumberFormatter` it is.

Comment: Nice, better than bla bla bla previous answers! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the `'` character

So, just have this:

```
NSString *priceString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"$ %.2f", price];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *formatedNumbers = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:myNumber numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```