# IS there any easier way to show $ currency format?(As specially commas) Can I integrate RE with Objective C code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, regex, cocoa-touch

I using X code 4.

And Making an US Currency Calculator.

My Aim is to display the numbers in proper format?

Like

$ 1,234

$12,100

$1,23,123

I dont want do this by appending , and string stuff.

Is there any easier way so that I can integrate any RE or 
any ruby or Python. Which will help me to make currency format.

Please show me easier way rather than long programming.

Comment: So let me understand this, rather than taking a string appending approach you would rather attempt to integrate another language such as Ruby or Python on the iPhone to get currency output??

Comment: Ya If it is easy actually I want to know how to integrate so using other languages work should be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) allows you to format currency. Example taken from [[iOS developer:tips];](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/formatting-numbers-nsnumberformatter-examples.html)

```
// Create formatter
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
//--------------------------------------------
// Format style as currency, output to console
//--------------------------------------------
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1234]];
NSLog(@"Output as currency: %@", formattedOutput);

//--------------------------------------------
// Change local and output as currency
//--------------------------------------------
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it_IT"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1234]];
NSLog(@"Output as currency - locale it_IT: %@", formattedOutput);

[locale release];
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer here: [Objective-C: How to format string as $ Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774982/objective-c-how-to-format-string-as-price)

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
... = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

By default it uses the locale of your system, but you can change that and lots of other properties, see the NSNumberFormatter API docs.