# How to format a currency String with commas?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, currency

I am getting result in string like this $100000. But i want this  string value is separated with "," like currency format. E.g.: 1,00,000. How do I format this string value like that?
 Please give suggestion for this.

Thanking in advance

Comment: What you're asking is actually a near-opposite of splitting a string. It is called formatting, and specifically in your case, currency formatting.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284724/is-there-any-easier-way-to-show-currency-formatas-specially-commas-can-i-int/7284807#7284807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
    NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";

    NSString * formattedAmount = [formatter stringFromNumber: @1000000.25];
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to format currency. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774982/objective-c-how-to-format-string-as-price) and [here](http://samuellam.wordpress.com/2008/08/03/objective-c-format-currency/) for starters. Those links mostly use a floating point number as a starting value for currency formatting. In your case you will also need to parse (maybe also clean up) the string value to make sure it is a valid number that can be formatted for currency. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240601/how-to-convert-a-string-to-float) for starters on that. There are many, many other examples available from a simple Google search.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberformat = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
numberformat.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
numberformat.currencyCode = @"USD";

NSString * amountformat = [numberformat stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1000000.25]]
```