# Xcode Iphone App: How to print price float

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: How to format string as $ Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774982/objective-c-how-to-format-string-as-price)

I have an App showing prices.
The prices are displayed that way:

```
[self makePrice];
itemPrice.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",tempPrice];
itemPrice.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

As a result big values are shown as: $ 12123041

I need it to be  $ 12,123,041

How can I do it?

Thanks. Appreciate your help
Tim

Comment: This one looks more like it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714090/how-to-format-a-currency-string-with-commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can do like this way:-

```
int tempPrice=123456;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempPrice];
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:yourNumber];

str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];

NSLog(@"my corrunsy === %@",str);
```

**output is**

hiiii === $123,456.00

Comment: Yes, that's working for me, thanks a lot ;) But can I also remove these .00 from the end, as i only have whole dollar prices

Comment: AH, done: [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; Thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempPrice];

NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];

itemPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
```

Comment: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter 'NSNumber'